# Can not compile a project with PDFNet jar in jdk 1.7

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror, pdfnet

I have started a java project. I want to use a library which is called PDFnet. But It gives error. Where do I make wrong?

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { //System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    //System.loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\BDagli\\Downloads\\PDFNetC64\\Lib\\PDFNet");
    boolean uninstallPrinterWhenDone = false; // change this to test the uninstallation functions
    PDFNet.initialize();
```

---

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;.....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no PDFNetC in java.library.path
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
  at pdftron.PDF.PDFNet.<clinit>(PDFNet.java:21)
  at com.pdf.net.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19)
```

Comment: What IDE do you use? If you're using Eclipse make sure that jar file is in your project's classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend putting any dll in the System32 folder (without a very good reason). At the very least you can end up using libraries you didn't intend to since System32 might be a higher priority folder for library loading. At the very least, use the PATH environment variable to specify the folder where PDFNetC.dll is.

However it is better to 'solve' the issue...
If you look at the Java samples that come with PDFNet, you will see the following file in all the JAVA sample folders, RunText.bat
which does the following.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set TEST_NAME=DigitalSignaturesTest
javac.exe -cp .;../../../Lib/PDFNet.jar *.java
java.exe -Djava.library.path=../../../Lib -classpath .;../../../Lib/PDFNet.jar %TEST_NAME%
endlocal
```

So you just need to set the **java.library.path** to the folder where PDFNetC.dll is in your IDE. I'm not sure how to set it in your IDE, but I'm sure it is easy to find.

Here is the fist link I found on google describing this variable better.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/377174/java/java/java-library-path

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse for IDE. Then I added. Are they enough? I don't have many experience

[image]

I SOLVED.

I put PDFNetC.dll into C:\Windows\System32

Answer (score 0):

In-case any folks using `Eclipse` come by this post, ensure your import of `PDFNet.jar` specifies the `Native library location` in Eclipse, like so:

[image: Eclipse Java Build Path - Native library location]

Where the directory I've specified in `Native library location` above contains the `PDFNetC.dll` (or `PDFNetC.so` for Linux, `PDFNetC.dylib` for Mac).

You can access the Java Build Path via:

[image]